# Server-side rendering in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, server-side-rendering

Hello Meteor.js experts,

If you make a GET request to any page you will get something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Some meta tags here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Bunch of scripts here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I mean head of site, a bunch of scripts and that's all. No any markup code. I understand that Meteor is client side rendering framework. I need generate html on server side with this head and scripts for SEO. I need this scripts in order my application work on the client side normally, as usual Meteor application.

I tried to use [Meteor-SSR](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr), but it's not generate the scripts and head.

Is there any way to get this code (or only scripts list) on server side? And can I handle this script list? Can I remove some scripts out of there?

Comment: I think you can not, as meteor compiles, cache and includes all required or created js and css files to client side on load. So its moteor engine decide what to be rendered at client side, you just can mention the package names.

Answer (score 0):

The "bunch of scripts" appears normally only in development mode.

Once you build for production (or simulate with `--production` flag), all of them (including your `app.js`) are bundled and minified into a single JS file. The scripts which are specific for debug are not included.

As to come back to your main concern, you could try [Meteor-SSR](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr) package:

> Now, you can render Blaze templates on the server very easily. And also, you can assign helpers for templates in the server as well.

An alternative which is not exactly SSR is the [Fast Render](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render) package:

> Fast Render can improve the initial load time of your app, giving you 2-10 times faster initial page loads. It provides the same effect as Server Side Rendering (SSR), but still sends data over the wire to avoid breaking one of Meteor’s core principles.

With this package, you keep the very same client-side rendering even at start up, but the initial data is sent within the HTML page, eliminating the waiting time for the script to subscribe and receive the data from that extra request.

Comment: Hey ghybs, thanks for your response. I know about those packages and unfortunately they not works correctly.

Comment: You would get answers more adequate to your situation if you state in your question what you have already tried.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add this to my question

Comment: Any idea if any of these suggested packages can work with react?